# android in app billing sample app doesn't let me change target

Tags: android, eclipse

I installed the in App Billing APP sample but get the following target error in eclipse for mac even though i created the new project with 2.3.3sdk:

```
[2011-11-03 17:56:07 - Dungeon] Unable to resolve target 'android-4'
```

I tried going to Eclipse->Preferences and changing the sdk target, but there is no indication of sdk change.  How do i find the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `android:targetSdkVersion` in the manifest or install the 1.6 (API 4) SDK platform from  the SDK manager.